# How many EVs do the Festival Plaza services give?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In the Festival Plaza you can have restaurants and bouncy houses that offer services to increase the EVs of a stat you want. I'm wondering how much each option increases EVs by. It's supposed to be a controlled way to raise EVs but it doesn't give you any numbers to control it properly.

Comment: Balloon castles? You mean bouncy houses?

Comment: Yes, im spanish and didnt know the english term XD

Comment: No worries. Just making sure we have the good terms to make the question clearer for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Bouncy Houses, the lowest level course gives 4 EVs to a Pokémon, doubling with each level.

- Level 1 course: 4 EVs
- Level 2 course: 8 EVs
- Level 3 course: 16 EVs
- Level 4 course: 32 EVs
- Level 5 course: 64 EVs
- Level 6 course: 128 EVs
- Level 7 course: 252 EVs

Restaurant values are unknown, but from the description they should be either 16 or 32 EVs.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Friendship Cafe & Friendship Parlor actually *lower* EVs, through the Sweets Sets and the Secret Meals.